# extjs datefilter question

Tags: extjs

In extjs GridFilters.js, we have :

```
 onStateChange : function (event, filter) {
......
...
 if ((this.autoReload || this.local) && !this.applyingState) {
//alert('Firing reload');
this.deferredUpdate.delay(this.updateBuffer);
}

}
```

I thought this means that whenever the

```
`this.deferredUpdate.delay(this.updateBuffer);`
```

was executed, the `reload` function would be called. But by putting alerts, I discover that this is not the case. reload is called only once as it should be) despite the

```
alert('Firing reload');
```

popping up multiple times. I am using a Date Filter for this example.

Why is this so? does not a call to `deferredUpdate.delay` automatically trigger the reload as per the GridFfilters.js class?

Answer (score 0):

The GridFilter is using Ext's DelayedTask delay method ([here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/DelayedTask.html#method-Ext.util.DelayedTask-delay)) which cancels any pending delayed methods and queues a new one. Hence you are getting multiple alerts, but only one refresh.

Comment: from the link, I got:: "The DelayedTask class provides a convenient way to "buffer" the execution of a method, * performing setTimeout where a new timeout cancels the old timeout. When called, the * task will wait the specified time period before executing. If durng that time period, * the task is called again, the original call will be cancelled. This continues so that * the function is only called a single time for each iteration." But even by setting updateBuffer =0, I do not get multiple refresh-es.